# Creating a full width search input in Bootstrap navbar that is always displayed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

## Goal

I am trying to create a Bootstrap navbar that includes a full width search input that is always displayed (when the navbar is both collapsed and uncollapsed) as well as a dropdown list immediately to the right of the search that is toggled as usual.

#### Uncollapsed

[image]

#### Collapsed

[image]

## My Solution

I was able to accomplish this by defining the search input inside the navbar header and applying some css to make it full width. However, in order to get the options dropdown to be displayed properly *and* maintain full width of the search input in *both* collapsed *and* uncollapsed views, I applied what I can only describe as a series of hacks. I would like help coming up with a proper solution.

#### First Hack

I defined the options inside the header. When I defined the options outside the header, I was either not able to get the search to maintain full width or not able to keep both the search and options on the same line, depending on different solutions I tried.

#### Second Hack

In order for the options to be displayed in the correct location relative to the search (to the right when uncollapsed and below when collapsed), I had to **duplicate** (terrible I know) the options div. I defined one before and one after the search input. I then applied css hacks to only show one of the two options depending on whether or not the navbar was collapsed.

## Question

I have created a stripped down [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QST723BqCq) that shows my working hacks. How can I accomplish this the **right** way? I'd be happy to completely abandon my approach in favor of a cleaner solution.

**Disclaimer**: I'm still pretty new to HTML/CSS and Bootstrap so I'm probably doing all kinds of things the wrong way.

## Relevant HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="SearchController">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-hack1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Options<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Some Options</li>
                            <li>
                              <select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option></select>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>            
            <div class="search form-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" role="search" id="query" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-hack2" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Options<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Some Options</li>
                            <li>
                              <select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option></select>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</nav>
```

## Relevant CSS

```
.navbar-header {
    float: none !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none !important;
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
        float: right !important;
    }

    .navbar-hack2.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .search {
        margin-right: 100px !important;
    }

    .search input {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-hack1 {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help or give you some ideas.

```css
/**Custom**/

body,
html {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.navbar-default .formSearch {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 85%;
}
.navbar-default #search-input {
  height: 50px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #444;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .navbar-default #search-input {
    width: 85%;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <form class="formSearch" role="search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for Something...">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-lg">
    <h1>Boostrap Search Bar</h1>

  </div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! I should be able to work this into my design pretty easily.

Comment: Positioning the search form / div using with "absolute" was the key to solving my problem.

Comment: No problem and glad i could help.